# Shell script- syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: shell-script, here-document

I'm practicing some scripts from a book and I keep getting an unexpected end-of-file syntax error. The images below show the error message and the script that uses basic commands to create a system-information html file. The second set of images show my attempt to comment out the problematic lines and run it.

In the top part I have three functions that use here-documents to generate html tags, I'm using the '<<-' switch to allow me to indent the tags for readability. My issue is that the error I mentioned keeps popping up. If I change it to 'echo' commands it works just fine, the weird part is I have a here-document at the bottom of the script, outside of a function and that works just fine if I comment out the three functions.
What I am I doing wrong?

[image: dual terminal view: error message and script file]

[image: working shoot of script with commented out functions]

Comment: Next time, please just use [code blocks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) instead of images.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was thinking it was hard to read any ways...and I just saw my terrible grammar, sorry.

Comment: Grammar is not a big deal, but you code is not readible without clicking (and not copyable). Copy your code over here, otherwise no-one will help you.

Comment: Please use text instead of images. We are not about to manually transcribe your code to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indenting the here-document end marker.

For it to be detected as such, the end marker must come at the beginning of a line of its own.

**Unindent the end marker** and you will likely find that your script works fine (at least as far as that goes).

Comment: Thank you very much that was the problem. I didn't even realize it, and not only where the markers indented but some even had trailing spaces. Greatly appreciate it Michael.